# Add dynamic Text update to pyQt script

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to add the ability to update a data field (number) on my current pyqt script. I was trying to use "addLabel" but I can't update their content dynamically.

Any suggestion on how to make it? I am using addPlot function to create the plots which will be processing some data from a UDP packet. In some cases, I want to just show the value dynamically. Not sure what will be the best widget to use for this purpose?

Current script:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
import struct
from struct import pack, unpack
import socket 

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

data = []
data_throttle = []
data_brake = []
data_steering = []
data_state = []
data_error = []

pg.setConfigOption('background', (0,0,0))
#pg.setConfigOption(antialias=True)
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.resize(500,200)
p1 = win.addPlot(title="Sequence")
p1.setWindowTitle('Sequence')
p1.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 150)) 
#p1.setLabel('bottom', 'Packet', units=' ')
p1.showGrid(True, True)

p2 = win.addPlot(title="Throttle")
p2.setWindowTitle('Throttle')
p2.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 255)) 
#p2.setLabel('bottom', 'Packet', units=' ')
p2.showGrid(True, True)

p3 = win.addPlot(title="Brake")
p3.setWindowTitle('Brake')
p3.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 255)) 
#p3.setLabel('bottom', 'Packet', units=' ')
p3.showGrid(True, True)


p4 = win.addPlot(title="Steering")
p4.setWindowTitle('Steering')
p4.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, -1, 100, 2)) 
#p4.setLabel('bottom', 'Packet', units=' ')git 
p4.showGrid(True, True)

p5 = win.addPlot(title="Vehicle State")
p5.setWindowTitle('Vehicle State')
p5.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 10)) 
#p5.setLabel('bottom', 'Packet', units=' ')
p5.showGrid(True, True)

p6 = win.addPlot(title="Errors")
p6.setWindowTitle('Errors')
p6.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 10)) 
#p6.setLabel('bottom', 'Packet', units=' ')
p6.showGrid(True, True)



top_label = "Percent"
bottom_label = "85"
l_labels = win.addLayout(col=1, colspan=1)
l_labels.addLabel(top_label, row=0, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1, size='30pt', bold=True)
l_labels.addLabel(bottom_label, row=2, col=0, rowspan=4, colspan=1, size='200pt', color='606060')
l_labels.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 100) 


curve = p1.plot(pen='r')
curve2 = p2.plot(pen='b')
curve3 = p3.plot(pen='g')
curve4 = p4.plot(pen='y')
curve5 = p5.plot(pen='r')
curve6 = p6.plot(pen='b')


# Receive UDP packets transmitted by a broadcasting service

RECEIVE_IP = ''
RECEIVE_PORT = 2337
RECEIVE_ADDRESS = (RECEIVE_IP, RECEIVE_PORT)


recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
recv_socket.bind(RECEIVE_ADDRESS)
JOY_CODE = '=HBBBhHQQB'
ACK_CODE = '=HHBBHBBhBqB'

ptr = 0
lastTime = time()
fps = None
def update():
    global recv_socket, fScale
    global curve, data, data_throttle, data_brake, data_steering, ptr, p, lastTime, fps, data_state, data_error
    recv_message, address = recv_socket.recvfrom(22)
    message_id, ack_payload, ack_seq, vehicle_state, vehicle_speed, throttle, brake, steering, error, timestamp, checksum =  struct.unpack(ACK_CODE, recv_message) 
    #data = throttle
    data.append(ack_seq)
    data =  data[-100:]
   
    data_throttle.append(throttle)
    data_throttle =  data_throttle[-100:]
   
    data_brake.append(brake)
    data_brake =  data_brake[-100:]
   
    data_steering.append(steering / 32768)
    data_steering =  data_steering[-100:]

    vehicle_state = vehicle_state & 0x07
    data_state.append(vehicle_state)
    data_state = data_state[-100:]

    data_error.append(error)
    data_error = data_error[-100:]
   

    #print(throttle)
    #print("got data", data, "  ", lastTime, "\n")
    # print data
    #curve.setData(fScale,data,_callSync='off')
    curve.setData(data,_callSync='off')
    curve2.setData(data_throttle,_callSync='off')
    curve3.setData(data_brake,_callSync='off')
    curve4.setData(data_steering,_callSync='off')
    curve5.setData(data_state, _callSync='off')
    curve6.setData(data_error, _callSync='off')
    bottom_label = vehicle_state
    
    now = time()
    dt = now - lastTime
    lastTime = now

    app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw for every plot
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure the solution by using TextItem inside a Plot

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
import struct
from struct import pack, unpack
import socket 

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

data = []
data_throttle = []
data_brake = []
data_steering = []
data_state = []
data_error = []


pg.setConfigOption('background', (0,0,0))
#pg.setConfigOption(antialias=True)
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.resize(1600,1000)
p1 = win.addPlot(title="Sequence",row=0, col=1)
p1.setWindowTitle('Sequence')
p1.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 150)) 
p1.showGrid(True, True)

p2 = win.addPlot(title="Throttle",row=0, col=2)
p2.setWindowTitle('Throttle')
p2.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 255)) 
p2.showGrid(True, True)

p3 = win.addPlot(title="Brake",row=0, col=3)
p3.setWindowTitle('Brake')
p3.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 255)) 
p3.showGrid(True, True)


p4 = win.addPlot(title="Steering",row=1, col=1)
p4.setWindowTitle('Steering')
p4.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, -1, 100, 2)) 
p4.showGrid(True, True)

p5 = win.addPlot(title="Vehicle State",row=1, col=2)
p5.setWindowTitle('Vehicle State')
p5.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 10)) 
p5.showGrid(True, True)

p6 = win.addPlot(title="Errors",row=1, col=3)
p6.setWindowTitle('Errors')
p6.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 10)) 
p6.showGrid(True, True)

p7 = win.addPlot(title="Counter",row=0, col=4)
p8 = win.addPlot(title="Counter",row=1, col=4)

font=QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(300)

anchor = pg.TextItem()
anchor.setText("0")
anchor.setColor(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
anchor.setFont(font)

anchor1 = pg.TextItem()
anchor1.setText("0")
anchor1.setColor(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
anchor1.setFont(font)


p7.addItem(anchor)
p7.showGrid(False, False)
p7.hideAxis('bottom')
p7.hideAxis('left')

p8.addItem(anchor1)
p8.showGrid(False, False)
p8.hideAxis('bottom')
p8.hideAxis('left')




curve = p1.plot(pen='r')
curve2 = p2.plot(pen='b')
curve3 = p3.plot(pen='g')
curve4 = p4.plot(pen='y')
curve5 = p5.plot(pen='r')
curve6 = p6.plot(pen='b')


# Receive UDP packets transmitted by a broadcasting service

RECEIVE_IP = ''
RECEIVE_PORT = 2337
RECEIVE_ADDRESS = (RECEIVE_IP, RECEIVE_PORT)


recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
recv_socket.bind(RECEIVE_ADDRESS)

JOY_CODE = '=HBBBhHQQB'


ACK_CODE = '=HHBBHBBhBqB'

ptr = 0
lastTime = time()
fps = None
def update():
    global recv_socket, fScale
    global curve, data, data_throttle, data_brake, data_steering, ptr, p, lastTime, fps, data_state, data_error
    recv_message, address = recv_socket.recvfrom(22)
    message_id, ack_payload, ack_seq, vehicle_state, vehicle_speed, throttle, brake, steering, error, timestamp, checksum =  struct.unpack(ACK_CODE, recv_message) 
    #data = throttle
    data.append(ack_seq)
    data =  data[-100:]
   
    data_throttle.append(throttle)
    data_throttle =  data_throttle[-100:]
   
    data_brake.append(brake)
    data_brake =  data_brake[-100:]
   
    data_steering.append(steering / 32768)
    data_steering =  data_steering[-100:]

    vehicle_state = vehicle_state & 0x07
    data_state.append(vehicle_state)
    data_state = data_state[-100:]

    data_error.append(error)
    data_error = data_error[-100:]
   

    curve.setData(data,_callSync='off')
    curve2.setData(data_throttle,_callSync='off')
    curve3.setData(data_brake,_callSync='off')
    curve4.setData(data_steering,_callSync='off')
    curve5.setData(data_state, _callSync='off')
    curve6.setData(data_error, _callSync='off')

    #Updating Text Value 
    anchor.setText(str(vehicle_state))
    anchor1.setText(str(vehicle_state))

    now = time()
    dt = now - lastTime
    lastTime = now
    app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw for every plot

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```